# Daylight savings time (DST) in javascript

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst

I want to calculate times (day is optional) in javascript correctly. This should also work for daylight savings time.

This is my current code which does not work with DST.

```
        let utcTime = "December 15, 2021 09:00:00"; 
        let date = new Date(utcTime)
        // getTimezoneOffset is in minutes, 60 sec * 1000 converts it to ms.
        let userTimezoneOffsetInMs = date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;
        let offsetTime = new Date(date.getTime() - userTimezoneOffsetInMs );
        let tzformat = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZoneName;    
        options = {
              hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric',
              timeZone: tzformat,
              timeZoneName: 'short'
        };
    
        let finalTime = new Intl.DateTimeFormat(Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().locale, options).format(offsetTime);
        console.log(finalTime)
```

I was hoping in year 2021, there has to be a better way to do this with native APIs. I did go thru stack overflow with answers dating back a decade. There are lots of answers with external library like moment.js

Comment: Check alternatives as provided here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/

Comment: What is it you are trying to "calculate" exactly?  It seems like you are just trying to convert a UTC value to the user's local time zone?

Comment: Yes that is what i am trying to do but it does not work with daylight savings time